# How can I determine which port will be assigned to a client?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Suppose I have a wcf service listening on a remote server.
Could a client, before connecting, know what port will be assigned by the operating system?

Comment: I would implement a duplex communication using `BasicHttpBinding`: when the node A sends a request to the node B, if node B accepts this request then the node A should reserve one of the available slots to the oncoming connection from B; but A could know only the IP address of B in order to reserve the slot, but not the port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not by default... however you can wrestle control away by using the [BindIPEndPointDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.bindipendpoint.aspx) property of the ServicePoint managing requests to that uri:

```
var servicePoint=ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(myServiceUri);
servicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = (sp, remoteEndPoint, retryCount) =>
    new IPEndPoint(localEndpointDetailsGoHere)
```

You'll need to manage ports yourself in this case.

Comment: Well, so I should specify `IPAddress.Loopback, myLocalPort`... Is it correct?

Comment: Yes... but if the port is in use or TIME_WAIT, IIRC the delegate is called again with an increased retry count.